# how to add custom callback URL to Coinbase

Tags: bitcoin, coinbase-api

I'm using Coinbase service to dealing with Bitcoin gateway.

I know i can put callback url in the `merchant settings page` of my account.

But i need to update it in each order. It can be done using API. but it's so boring.

I need something like this :

Adding **data-callback="custom_callback_url"** in the Anchor tag.

```
<a class="coinbase-button" 
data-code="code_here" 
data-callback="custom_callback_url" 
href="https://coinbase.com/checkouts/code_here">Pay With Bitcoin</a>

<script src="https://coinbase.com/assets/button.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Answer (score -1):

With coinbase's API, you will have to set the callback URL while generating the code!

There is more info on how to generate the code here: https://coinbase.com/api/doc/1.0/buttons/create.html